# Error al momento del deployming en render

Tags: mysql, nodejs

Me sale este error al momento de intentar subir mi proyecto hecho con node.js desde render

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDsv3.png)

ciertamente no se como detener esas conexiones, o que solución implementar, gracias por leer :)

Código

https://github.com/EduardoPoot-dev/agencia-viajes-2

My base de datos Mysql esta alojado en filess, la versión del motor es la 5.7.38

Ya cerré todo lo necesaro a nivel local relacionado con mysql y no funcionó :(